# Subtitles vs closed captioning translation difference on Netflix?(specific to Funimation titles)

Tags: resources

If anyone has Netflix in here, I have a question about the difference in Funimation subtitles vs closed captioning, which I'm guessing is provided by Netflix.

Not that I really even use Netflix for anime, but I have tried a few series and noticed Funimation titles have both, a **Subtitles** as well as a **Closed Caption** option, with different translations on both... not just the audible sounds and what not. Subtitles always being coded in yellow and CC being encoded in white.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Im guessing the yellow encoded subs are from the DVD localization, and then the white CC are a resub, relicensed through Netflix??

Comment: Subtitles are the translation of the Japanese, while CC (should be) what's being said in English.

Answer (score 2):

Closed captioning (CC) and subtitling are both processes of displaying text on a television, video screen, or other visual display to provide additional or interpretive
information. Basically, both are the same. But looking into it technically, CC offers more.

From [Wikipedia article on Closed Captioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_captioning):

> HTML5 defines **subtitles** as a "transcription or translation of the dialogue ... when sound is available but not understood" by the viewer (for example, dialogue in a foreign language)

and

> **captions** as a "transcription or translation of the dialogue, sound effects, relevant musical cues, and other relevant audio information ... when sound is unavailable or not clearly audible" (for example, when audio is muted or the viewer is hearing impaired).

To put it in simple words, subtitles display the dialogue whereas CC  is meant to replace sound, not just dialogue.

About your question, in most cases, the CC differs very much from the subtitles. This is because, in this case, Netflix, not only focuses on what's being said, but also on pretty much everything thats going on around. Subtitles, like you mentioned in your question, are often DVD localisations. But the CC  available on Netflix could be

1. made by the employees.
2. made by Audio Recognition softwares.
3. submitted by users or volunteers.

Therefore it leaves a significant margin for error. Hence resulting in the obvious difference between the subtitles and CC. I dont use Netflix, but it seems the matter is not exclusive to Funimation series.

And the color of the texts, I guess is just to imply that subtitles will be yellow colored while CC white.

Source(s):
http://theweek.com/articles/452181/how-netflix-alienated-insulted-deaf-subscribers